# Sketch App with label colors on Sidebar

Tags: sketch-app, interface-design

In the Sketch App I have at home, he displayed a few different items on siderar than I use at work. Basically you have the option of selecting label colors for artboards and layers and also a line next to the layers. I would like to enable this at work, would anyone know how to enable this? Thanks for the thought.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I did some tests activating / deactivating the plugins, and this feature is activated by the https://midnightsketch.com plugin.

[image]